# Jaheira appears as a dead body in temple of Amanuator

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

After defeating Bodhi I took Jaheira's body and Bodhi's black heart to the statue in the temple of Amanuator, and Jaheira appears- as a dead body, which I can't interact with in any way.

This seems like a bug. Is there some way to circumvent it, perhaps with the CLUA console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out. When Bodhi vampifies Jaheira in the graveyard entrance, Jaheira remains in the area as a vampire and joins the rest of the vampires. In my original playthrough, I killed this vampire Jaheira with the rest of the vampire party. It turns out that this Jaheira in-game "object" is the same Jaheira "object" that you get after you perform the ritual, and since I killed it in the graveyard, after the ritual I got it in a dead state. On my next attempt, I tried to just run away from her and go straight for the catacombs. This time, once I tried to resurrect Jaheira in the temple of Amanuator, an enemy Jaheira appeared (again- retaining the state it had in the graveyard), but since her restoration dialogue was immediately initiated, I got her to rejoin the party as an ally.